# Hide certain characters in a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to hide all instances of certain characters contained in a simple div.
Basically what I'm after is that when the page loads certain characters (in this instance 's' and 'e') will fade out and leave spaces in the sentence where the characters would have been.
This is as far as I've got so far:
HTML:
`<div id="test">hello this is a test this is a test</div>`​

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#test').html($('#test').html().replace("s"," "));
$('#test').html($('#test').html().replace("e"," "));
});​
```

Here's a working jsFiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/6vjt3/ 
but all this is doing is hiding the first 's' and 'e' in the sentence, and not the rest.
Preferably what I'd like to happen is that the jQuery would detect these letters and slowly fade them to white, therefore leaving a space proportional to the letter, can't figure out how to do this at all though.
Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-replace This should help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do as you mentioned about fading it out.. See **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/6vjt3/3/

**Full Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var charToReplace = ['s', 'e'];
    $('#test').html(function (i, v) {
        var resultStr = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++ ) {
            var ch = v.charAt(i);

            if ($.inArray(ch, charToReplace) >= 0) {
               resultStr += '<span class="hideMe">' + ch + '</span>';  
            } else {
               resultStr += ch;
            }
        }

        return resultStr;
    }).find('.hideMe').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', 0).show();            
    });

    //lets bring it all back
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#test').find('.hideMe').css('opacity', 1);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Use regEx with `g` (global) on replace.. See below,

```
$('#test').html($('#test').html().replace(/s/g," "));
$('#test').html($('#test').html().replace(/e/g," "));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6vjt3/1/

Comment: This code works great, perfect in fact!! One small problem though, for some reason after this code is used it is no longer implemented the <b r > tags within the div, is there a reason for this?

Comment: @user1374796 Post a sample text with `<br>` and I will look into it.

Comment: I've managed to figure that out, but for some reason when I've moved the code over to my server, it's failing to work at all? http://www.nealfletcher.co.uk/fish/test/test Can't figure out why

Comment: @user1374796 You need to include `jquery.js`. You can get a copy from http://code.jquery.com/

Comment: I'd tried that, if you go back on you'll see jquery.js is included but still the script isn't working for some reason?

Comment: `Timestamp: 12/5/2012 11:33:45 AM
Error: SyntaxError: illegal character
Source File: http://www.nealfletcher.co.uk/fish/test/test
Line: 51, Column: 3
Source Code:
});​ ` Is the error I am seeing in the console.

Comment: Line 51 is the closing }); tag, but I also tried transferring the code over to another site which had working jquery and it still didn't work? Can't figure out why at all

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to go back to the original data later, I suggest this approach:

```
var $hiddenElement = $('<span>').addClass('hidden');

$('#test').html($('#test').html().replace(/s/g, $hiddenElement.text(s)));
$('#test').html($('#test').html().replace(/e/g, $hiddenElement.text(s)));
```

Your CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap these characters in a SPAN then fade out the SPAN. Using replace will get rid of them instantly, but will never fade-out.